# Apps Script: How to know the Last Row of a Merged cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, row

How to know the last row of a merged cell, like for example

[image]

In the above sheet if somebody edits range A2 containing value `a`, `onEdit()` method will be triggered. I can get to know the row and column of the edited cell using `range.getRow()` and `range.getColumn()` like this

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var Row = range.getRow();
  var Col = range.getColumn();
}
```

How to know the last row of a merged cell like for `a` it is `10`, for `b` it is `12`, for `c` it is `20`, for `one` it is `7` and so on using Apps script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the edited cell is part of a merged cell you can use this.

```
  if( e.range.isPartOfMerge() ) {
    var range = e.range.getMergedRanges()[0];
    var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
  }
  else {
    // You figure it out
  }
```

Comment: As per the question I wanted to know the last row of the merged cell so adding to your answer `lastRow = range.getLastRow();` will work.
Please modify your answer to accommodate this then I will accept your answer as a right answer.